# facing issue with HtmlUnitDriver

Tags: java, selenium, htmlunit

I am using HtmlUnitDriver to open a link.
Here is my code:

```
HtmlUnitDriver webDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
webDriver.get("some url here");
```

But I am getting following exception.

```
Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Wrapped com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Wrapped com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function aa in object [object Object]. (https://apis.google.com/_/apps-static/_/js/gapi/plusone/rt=j/ver=use0LfpKko4.en_US./sv=1/am=!CVDWKorrwvOYBs7wcQ/d=1/rs=AItRSTMxl0wiQySaT0IYW5gyOkdlVL9A6A/cb=gapi.loaded_0#3)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:595)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:537)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:538)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:499)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:973)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:349)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$1.execute(HtmlScript.java:230)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:240)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:598)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:556)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1142)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1044)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:329)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3018)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2005)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:908)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:789)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:225)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:179)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:221)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:106)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:433)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:311)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:373)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:346)
    ... 15 more
```

Please guide me,how to solve this.I am using selenium-java-2.24.1.jar,webdriver-common.jar.

Comment: `HTMLUnit` is having difficulty executing a JavaScript function.  It's pretty difficult to diagnose the problem unless you can give a little more background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exception says driver is facing problem with Javascript function while loading the page, By default HTMLUNITDriver disables Javascript.

You need to explicitly enable it and then try to navigate the URL
Try this and it should work.

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
```

True --> Here it mentions to enable Java script.

Moreover javascript engine used by HtmlUnitDriver is different from other browsers.Check this link for more details.

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#htmlunit-driver

Answer (score 3):

> driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);

Add one more line -

> java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);

Answer (score 2):

You might like to try this one.

It is working fine for me. This is Scala code you might want to make minor changes for Java.

```
val  driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6)
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true)
driver.get(your_url)
driver.getTitle() must contain("Welcome")
```